# Trying to find an older book where the main character gets pulled into a parallel universe where people fight with powered armor and energy swords

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

From what I remember it was a book series and I picked it up from a 2nd hand store in the 1990s. Not sure when it was published.

In the first book a cop? gets pulled into a parallel universe where they use suits of powered armor.   These suits protect them and allow them to generate a sword of energy to fight with.

If I remember its set as if it was medieval times and they were kind of like knights.

As a last ditch effort (from the crappy first suit he wore) he was able to fire all the energy out of the palm of his suit and it burned a small hole in his enemy's suit allowing him to win.

If you win, you get the other persons suit of energy.

That's about all I got, anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about the Northworld books by David Drake.  I'm not sure exactly how many there are, but several are available for free on iBooks, so if you have an apple device it should be easy to locate some of them.
   The events you describe occur, by memory, in there first book of the *Northworld Trilogy*.