# Sci fi book about knights with swords and armor and "arc" weapons

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't know a whole lot about this book I read years ago other than the fact that I remember LOVING it and really would love to read it again.  I want to say that I read it in the late 80s and that it was written about the same time. I remember the cover being black and white split down the middle. Possibly with some sort of helmet on it...

The basic premise of the book is that there are knights but they fight with swords that I remember them calling "arc" something or other. It was a futuristic book and there were suits are armor and that was where the arc's came from.  Kind of a lightsaber sort of thing. I remember there was a quest but don't remember anything about that side of it.  I also seem to remember there being a time travel element to it.

Please help me find this book!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The "arc" weapons is teasing me, I've read something very similar. I don't remember it as arc, though, but something else. Argh.

Comment: i know John!  Its been driving me nuts!

Comment: @JohnP Although not related to the answer below, you may be thinking the force blades in M. John Harrison's Viriconium books, the *baan*.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89830/trying-to-find-an-older-book-where-the-main-character-gets-pulled-into-a-paralle

Answer (score 14):

Sounds somewhat like the *[Northworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northworld)* series by David Drake.

Excerpt from Wikipedia:

> The people, though they live in primitive conditions with little technology, have very sophisticated powered armor. This Armor has one major weapon, an electric arc extending from the suit's gauntlets.

Comment: I have the Northworld books, and I agree with revenant that they sound very like the book in question. The covers don't match the description, but covers tend to vary between reprints. The books do involve knights in armour fighting each other with energy weapons called "arcs".

Comment: OH MY GOSH i think that might be it!!!  Holy cow you all are awesome!!!!  i'll check it out and let you know!

Comment: @Nathan Can you confirm whether this was definitely the answer?